# C++ multithreading and passing templated arguments <typename T>(T arg)

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, arguments

I have this code which is working without anny issue:

```
void function_exit(dispatcher& d) { /* .. */ }
// ...
std::thread th(function_exit, std::ref(main_disp));
th.detach();
```

now I tried create another class which hold `std::thread` which produce errors on compilation

```
thread_control mtc;
mtc.create<dispatcher&>(function_exit, main_disp);
```

here is create function: (please read a comented text for describing a problem)

```
template<typename Arg>
inline bool thread_control::create(void(*function)(Arg), Arg value)
{
    bool ok = false;
    if (created == false)
    {
        created = true;
        if (typeid(Arg).hash_code() == typeid(void).hash_code())
        {
            // this produce thread(50,5): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
            // type_traits(1583): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
            // thread(50,5): message : With the following template arguments:
            // thread(50,5): message : '_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(Arg)'
            m_thread = std::thread(function);
        }
        else
        {
            if (std::is_reference<Arg>::value)
            {
                // if only this function is used, program is compiled without errors and runs without problem.
                // (when i comment functions which are problematic and this function is uncomented)
                m_thread = std::thread(function, std::ref(value)); 
            }
            else
            {
                // this function produce this errors:
                // 2>...\Visual Studio 2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\thread(65): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int (__stdcall *std::thread::_Get_invoke<_Tuple,0,1>(std::integer_sequence<size_t,0,1>) noexcept)(void *)' being compiled
                // thread(50,5): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
                // type_traits(1589): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
                // thread(50,5): message : With the following template arguments:
                // thread(50,5): message : '_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(Arg)'
                // thread(50,5): message : '_Ty1=dispatcher'
                // thread(50,5): message : '_Types2={}'
                // thread(50,5): error C2780: 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)': expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
                // type_traits(1583): message : see declaration of 'std::invoke'
                m_thread = std::thread(function, value);
            }
        }
        ok = true;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

What is wrong with my `m_thread = std::thread(...);` functions which throw those compilation errors? Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (std::is_reference<Arg>::value)
```

For a given `Arg`, this will evaluate to either `true` or `false`, of course.

However ***both*** the code that executes when this condition is true, and the code that executes when this condition is false ***must be valid C++***.

```
 m_thread = std::thread(function, value);
```

If `Arg` is a reference, this is not valid C++. Even though the `if` condition will evaluate to `true`, and this will not get executed, this ***still must be valid C++***.

There are two basic approaches that can be used here.

1. Use `if constexpr` with C++17, and higher.
2. With C++14 and earlier you will need to rewrite the whole thing to use specialization (of this entire template function, or by moving the relevant logic into template classes and specializing them).